# How is :fin being used?

Tags: clojure

In the Clojure [Koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans) :fin is being used in atoms.clj. Here is one example:

```
(def atomic-clock (atom 0))

  "Atomic atoms are atomic"
  (= 20 (do
          (compare-and-set! atomic-clock 100 :fin)
          @atomic-clock))
```

I understand that :fin is the new value. But why is it being used instead of number?

I've searched the documentation for :fin being used and cannot find its use other than in the Koans.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure, the colon makes something called a keyword, or a key:

```
user=> (type :xyz)
clojure.lang.Keyword
```

Keys are used in maps, because they're easy to check for equality and to convert to strings.  You can see that, later in the same file, `:fin` is used again in a check for equality:

```
(= :fin (do
        (compare-and-set! __ __ __)
        @atomic-clock)))
```

Comment: So it's nothing more than someone wanted a keyword to indicate a particular value. I thought there was something special about :fin. Thanks.